# How to iterate on a conditional array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I iterate through files in Perl and I'd like to get the correct "Adresse" field in the file. "Adresse" is a hash. Either the file contains only one "Adresse", and I take it, or it contains several "Adresse" and "Adresse" is actually an Array containing several "Adresse", and I just need the one having "type" = "postale".
Here is my code:

```
  my $ad;
  my $adresse;
  if(ref($doc->{'Organisme'}->{'Adresse'}) eq 'ARRAY') {
    print "\nI'M AN ARRAY!\n";
    foreach $ad ($doc->{'Organisme'}->{'Adresse'}) {
      print Dumper $ad;
      if ($ad->{'type'} == 'postale') {
       my $adresse = $ad;
      }
    }
  } else {
    my $adresse = $doc->{'Organisme'}->{'Adresse'}
  }
  print $fd $adresse->{'Ligne'};
```

I get the error:

```
Not a HASH reference at ./scripts/actualiserDonnees.pl line 35
```

and line 35 is:

```
if ($ad->{'type'} == 'postale') {
```

Apparently the "foreach" doens't iterate through "$doc->{'Organisme'}->{'Adresse'}" when the latter is an array, because the Dumper gives me this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'Localisation' => {
                                "Pr\x{e9}cision" => '8',
                                'Longitude' => '1.9751304',
                                'Latitude' => '43.2279035'
                              },
            'type' => 'physique',
            'CodePostal' => '11270',
            "Accessibilit\x{e9}" => {
                                      'type' => 'ACC'
                                    },
            'NomCommune' => 'Laurac',
            'Ligne' => 'Place Blanche-de-Laurac'
          },
          {
            'Ligne' => '8 rue du Pont',
            'CodePostal' => '11270',
            'type' => 'postale',
            'NomCommune' => 'Laurac'
          }
        ];
```

If I didn't explain myself enough, feel free to ask questions.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try to remove the braces from `($doc->{'Organisme'}->{'Adresse'})`, maybe perl treats this as a list of one Array, Ah long time since i used Perl, shouldn't it be @ad?

Comment: Sorry, I meant  %ad

Comment: I tried this, but actually the solution given below by ikegami is correct.

Comment: I was the first to give it an upvote :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my $adresse` creates a new variable. Replace both instances of `my $adresse = ...` with `$adresse = ...`

---

`$doc->{'Organisme'}->{'Adresse'}` is a scalar (a reference to an array), so `foreach $ad ($doc->{'Organisme'}->{'Adresse'})` only loops over one item (the reference to an array). You want `foreach $ad (@{ $doc->{'Organisme'}->{'Adresse'} })`

Comment: Thank you, the "my" was an copy/paste error, I didn't have it in my code, which was more complicated. The "@" thing did the trick. I tried @$doc before that, now thanks to you I understand more why I've been wrong.

Comment: or in perl 5.24 or later, `foreach $ad ($doc->{'Organisme'}{'Adresse'}->@*)`